# CollectionView cells not able to animate frame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

It's late and I'm too dumb at this point to figure out what the hell is going on. Does anyone see any glarring errors here.

I'm trying to animate the frame of a collectionview cell when the user presses on it.

heres my code from the view controller.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Highlighted");
    [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] shrinkCell:YES];


}
```

And here is my code inside the cell

```
-(void)shrinkCell:(BOOL)shrink{
    NSLog(@"Shrink");


    if (shrink) {


        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.bg.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bg.frame, 100, 100);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem i'm running in to is the animation immediately completes. It has no delay and the no duration. And I cannot figure out why. Anyone have any tips or thoughts?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it has something to do with it, but, where do those cells come from in this line?

```
[[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] shrinkCell:YES];
```

Why aren't you using?:

```
[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Because that doesnt let me have access to the cells methods. Or at least thats what was working for me. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Why not? Just cast it to your cell class: MyCell* cell = (MyCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: but wouldn't that essentially be the same thing that I'm currently doing? Or does that have a difference?

Comment: As I don't know where your cells array comes from, I can't say. Try it, won't take you long.

Answer (score 0):

Try animating the `center` property instead of `frame`. My guess is that your frame is for some reason no longer animatable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Highlighted");
    UICollectionViewCell  *animateCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self shrinkCell:YES andCell:animateCell];
}
-(void)shrinkCell:(BOOL)shrink andCell:(UICollectionViewCell*)animCell{
    NSLog(@"Shrink");


    if (shrink) {


        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             animCell.frame = CGRectOffset(animCell.frame, 100, 100);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same. It moves, just no animation what-so-ever

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and not :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: SO are you tapping and holding a cell ?